# How to append a control character to a string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, sockets, character-encoding

I see similar answers here but none are what I need.

I am trying to build a socket acknowledgement where the string message starts with a `0B` control character and has both a hex `1C` and a hex `0D` at the end of the transaction.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char b = '\u000b'; 
char c = '\u001c';
char d = '\u000d';
sb.Append(b);
sb.AppendLine(ackMessage);
sb.Append("MSA|AA|" + controlID);
sb.Append(c);
sb.Append(d);
string myMessage = sb.ToString();
```

The receiver of the message is not seeing the control characters at the beginning and end of the block, and I'm not sure where I am coding wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't know how to copy the code here in proper format so please forgive the formatting of this question ;)

Thanks.

Greg

Comment: Can you debug the function to see if `myMessage` has the control characters?

Comment: How exactly are you sending the string?

Comment: You can use the standard escape codes instead of the hex number of the key code. `\b \r \n` See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings and chars in .NET are Unicode.  Is your consumer expecting Unicode?  Maybe you need to create / pass a ASCII byte array instead?

```
    byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ackMessage);
    var asciiBytes = new List<byte>(ackMessage.Length + 3);
    asciiBytes.Add(0x0b);
    asciiBytes.AddRange(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII, unicodeBytes));
    asciiBytes.AddRange(new byte[] { 0x1c, 0x0d });
```

Comment: Or to be pedantic, UTF-16. You have a point though; we don't know how the string is sent.

Comment: Guys, I REALLY appreciate the quick response. The consumer suggested the ASCII byte array as well, but I was still stuck on why I couldnt get the control character appended. I am going to debug the function as suggested. Whats funny is as soon as foson asked if the consumer was expecting Unicode I noticed other issues in my code as well. I have to go crunch some numbers and I will repost my findings. I have been working with code for some years now, but this is the first interface I have built for an outside company and its not the easiest project ;) Thanks again for the immediate replies.

Comment: Thanks guys...the ASCII byte array worked out perfectly. We are having a new problem now (of course) which I added to my question above, but I am going to post as a new topic under the heading 'truncated socket message'. Thanks again so much.

Comment: Format on SO is QandA. Could you post a new question and mark this as answered?

Comment: You'll get more responses as a new, unanswered question.